# Were any tobacco industry funded studies published in peer reviewed journals?

Tags: academia

It is well known that the tobacco industry used the tactic of funding research which would come to conclusions that were in their interests, even though it contested other research findings. Specifically, they attempted to have research demonstrate that smoking cigarettes was okay.

Did any of the industry funded research arguing that smoking cigarettes is not bad for you ever end up being published in respectable peer reviewed journals?

---

Update: I have updated the question to be more specific. While I do realize that many industries fund research for their benefit, I wanted to keep the scope on the history of the tobacco industry, specifically their research that attempted to state that smoking cigarettes was safe.

Comment: Yes. Jean-Pierre Changeux (who recently asserted that nicotine blocks CoVi19) received funding from the CTR and published in Nature (1999) about the benefits of nicotine. A long article with details appeared in Le Monde (in French but google translate helps!) https://www.lemonde.fr/sciences/article/2012/05/31/guerre-du-tabac-la-bataille-de-la-nicotine_1710837_1650684.html

Comment: @sand1  I don't think nicotine research is the main intent here; rather studies suggesting that inhaling tobacco smoke might be less than desctructive to the lungs.  (nicotine doesn't harm the lungs the way all the particles and tar do)

Comment: Strange question. Industries can fund research, and this research can be published in peer-reviewed journals. What is special about tobacco industry which does not apply to automobile industry, for example, or to the research sponsored by army or navy?

Comment: Folks to research: https://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php?title=WhiteCoats_(SGDoc_1988)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I realize that this question could apply to many industries, but I wanted to narrow the scope to the tobacco industry. And yes, my question was specifically about the fact that the tobacco industry attempted to argue that smoking cigarettes was safe. I will update my question to reflect this.